# Как возвратить набор полей от запроса SQL?

Tags: php

Сейчас делаю так:

```
function Get(){
    if(mysql_num_rows($this->resQuery) > 0){
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($this->resQuery)
    }
}

function init(){
   $row = Get();
   while($row){
      echo $row['title']; // Выводит только одну запись
   }
}
```

Как вывести все записи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_fetch_assoc — Возвращает ряд результата запроса в качестве ассоциативного массива

function Get(){
    if(mysql_num_rows($this->resQuery) > 0){
        return $this->resQuery;
    }
}

function init(){
   $resQuery = Get();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resQuery)){
      echo $row['title']; \\ Выводит по очереди все записи
   }
}
```